# DigitalOcean Rails 4 Site not loading some images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a site using capistrano to DigitalOcean, and I'm stuck with a problem where *some* images don't display. I say some, because some do display properly (with the right `assets/...` URL) while some images in the same div don't display (instead trying to access some `images/...` path).

The weird part is these images are all in the same folder (`assets/images`), used in the same `each` loop, all using the `<%= image_tag %>` tag.

During deployment, `rake assets:precompile` always succeeds and there's no visible error.

And lastly, here's a part of my production.rb file:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

If you need any other code snippets, let me know and I'll provide them asap.

EDIT:

Changing `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `config.serve_static_assets = true` doesn't change the result in any way.

Comment: You should do this config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: @SSR doesn't work either :s

Comment: Do rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production on server. or try to run your site on development environment on server.